# Changing canonical questions

Tags: discussion

I think we can all agree that this has become a canonical question: [How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu)

I would like to create my own, better version.

If I were to do so, would the community be okay with changing which question we use for dupes of installing Android Studio?

---

Here's why I'd like to create an entirely new question and answer:

The current best-voted answer:

- Won't work for 64-bit Ubuntu because it doesn't mention that you have to install the 32-bit libs
- Says to add a PPA to get Java, and AFAIK Android Studio now bundles a JDK, so you wouldn't even need to get Java
- Lists a long procedure for creating a `.desktop` file, when there is already an option to create one automatically from within Android Studio's main menu
- Doesn't mention you should download the separate SDK package

---

FYI, I'd be okay with making the answer a community wiki if everyone really wants that; rep farming isn't my intent, although I wouldn't mind some extra rep :)

Comment: What about adding another answer on that question?

Comment: Firstly, it is really arrogant to assume your answer will be the best. Basically you are saying "I don't want to compete with the other answers, my answer is so good that the other question can just be closed and send all the votes to me". That is not how the site works, you can answer the question if you want and if the answer is taht good, you don't need to think about the others, you will get votes anyway.

Comment: @MarkKirby - No, it's not like that at all. It's just that I don't think anybody will ever bother to even try my answer if it's buried at the very bottom. :(

Comment: Then it is exactly like that, you don't want to compete. Can you give a reason why your answer is so good, a whole new question need to be created? That is the angle you need to come at this form, you need to justify a whole new question, at the expense of closing a very popular one. "It's just that I don't think anybody will ever bother to even try my answer if it's buried at the very bottom." You are wrong, your answer is the newest, many people will look for up to date answers over high voted ones. I have added to old questions and made good rep.

Comment: @MarkKirby - I'm not trying to rep farm. But the current highest-voted answer is wrong on many counts, the biggest of which is it won't even work for 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Then you need to explain all that in your post and give good detail why your answer would be better. If answers are objectively wrong, you can ask mods to remove them, no one wants wrong answers.

Comment: That was a really lazy edit, not exactly going to get your point across. You need to give details of WHY the other answers are wrong and should be removed or the question needs to be closed.

Comment: @MarkKirby - I know, I'm working on a better edit as I type this.

Comment: @MarkKirby - See updated post.

Comment: Hey, where *is* your answer?  I went to look for it to see if it was worth upvoting, but coulnd't find anything!

Comment: @Fabby - I haven't finished it yet. It's going to be very high-quality with lots of screenshots and everything, but I've been really busy, so I haven't had  much time to work on it. I'll ping you with the link when it is done though :)

Comment: @AndroidDev: Good!  **;-)**

Answer (score 6):

My personal take - I don't think it's the right way to go. That post has been worked on by many folks and has lots of votes and views and is going to be found by searches and so on.

It seems to me that the way to do things (and what seems to be the way it works in general) is to make the canonical post as good as possible. If there are problems with the current answers, then, edit & update them, flag them, comment on them. If you think a new answer is needed, then write one and let it gather votes as it should if it's superior, or offer a bounty (or find someone with more points to spare and persuade them it's necessary) to get more attention?

## TL;DR

The canonical post is a community effort, and as such deserves care and respect, and I'm inclined to favour it over a hypothetical unilateral effort. Let's not abandon that post & that effort and start over just because it's not perfect - let's make it better instead?

Comment: But I thought edits that deviated too much from the author's original version are frowned upon?

Comment: @AndroidDev well, yes, but you could make your edits low-impact by adding update notes and options rather than replacing anything. But in this case, the authors of the top two posts are both fairly active I think - you could comment (draw their attention to your question here?) and suggest improvements.

Comment: Well, I'd rather write my own answer from scratch. I'll wait for some more opinions, but I think that's what I'll do.

Comment: I think that's fine, make sure to ping me so I can upvote it @AndroidDev :)

Comment: Thanks, that's a really nice gesture :)

Answer (score 3):

I would just fix the answer.

It has 140k+ views and the top answer has the user installing a PPA. Our primary job is to make the internet suck less for Ubuntu users, so let's make the answer suck less, what's wrong with just adding the right fixes?